Hasura GraphQL doesn't have mutation option
I'm new to Hasura. I just setup Hasura and connect it with MongoDB.
I follow the instruction according to the guide here: https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/atlas/graphql-apis-hasura/
The database is connected, and the queries are working(execept the mutation).
However, there's a problem with Hasura GraphQL interface as image below:

in the "Add New" there's no mutation option.
Also when I write a simple mutation by myself, the error shows "no mutations exist" as image below:

I'm thinking if it is due to the write permission in MongoDB is set to false. But how can I set it up?
Need some help.
Thanks
